# PowerShell Converting $null into 0

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, powershell-2.0

I have a pretty straight-forward function for grabbing SQL results:

```
function RunSqlCommand($sql)
{
    $connection = $null
    $command = $null
    try
    {
        $connectionString = "data source=localhost; integrated security=true"
        $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $sql
        $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($command)
        $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $adapter.Fill($dataSet)
        $results = $dataSet.Tables | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Rows"
        return $results
    }
    finally
    {
        if ($command -ne $null) { $command.Dispose() }
        if ($connection -ne $null) { $connection.Dispose() }
    }
}
```

Whenever there are no results, the `$results` variable is `$null`. However, when I inspect the return value in the calling method, it magically becomes `0`.

Is PowerShell doing something behind the scenes? I really do want to return `$null` to represent "no results".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$adapter.Fill()` returns the number of rows added or refreshed in the dataset.

To fix, you can do this:

```
[void]$adapter.Fill($dataSet)
```

or

```
$adapter.Fill($dataset) | out-null
```

Comment: So, even though I am explicitly returning a value powershell is returning additional values? Why don't I get 0 when there are rows to return?

Comment: Found a pretty good blog explaining this behavior: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/effective-powershell-item-7-understanding-output/

Comment: This is a unique behavior of PowerShell that any "uncaptured" value gets added to the output stream.